# Basic Teradata SQL add column and summing columns

Tags: sql, teradata

Not great with SQL, so sorry if my questions seem dumb. I have this working code that pulls the entry date and the number of people that entered Store 1 on that date.

```
select entry_date as Enter_Date
    ,count(entry_date) as Entries
    from db_entry
    where entry_date between '2017-03-05' and '2017-03-11'
    and entry_code like 'STR1%'
    group by entry_date
```

This is what it shows up as

```
Enter_Date  Entries
3/5/2017    35
3/9/2017    30
3/10/2017   27
3/8/2017    23
3/7/2017    29
3/6/2017    32
3/11/2017   39
```

I was wondering if there was a way to add another column for store 2, where the entry_code is 'STR2%'. The reason I'm not sure what to do is because I'm not pulling a different column from the db_entry, so I'm not sure how to differentiate the two columns in the WHERE clause.

In addition, I was wondering if there was a quick way to sum each column and have the latest date as the Enter Date. Ideally this is what I'd like my table to look like:

```
 Enter_Date  Store 1     Store 2 
 3/11/2017   215         301
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting.

```
select entry_date as Enter_Date,
       count(case when entry_code like 'STR1%' then entry_date end) as Entries1,
       count(case when entry_code like 'STR2%' then entry_date end) as Entries2
from db_entry
where entry_date between '2017-03-05' and '2017-03-11'
  and entry_code like any ('STR1%', 'STR2%')
group by entry_date
```

Note: The `WHERE` clause's `like` str1/str2 isn't really needed now, but may perhaps speed the query up.

**Edit:** Now using `like any`, as suggested by @Dudu Markovitz!

Comment: `between date '2017-03-05' and date '2017-03-11'`

Comment: `entry_code like any ('STR1%','STR2%')` (Teradata supported syntax)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, thanks for the improvement suggestions! Just curios, is there a `like all` too?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 2nd question, simply remove the `GROUP BY` and switch to:

```
select MAX(entry_date) as Enter_Date,
       count(case when entry_code like 'STR1%' then entry_date end) as "Store 1",
       count(case when entry_code like 'STR2%' then entry_date end) as "Store 2"
from db_entry
where entry_date between date '2017-03-05' and date '2017-03-11'
  and entry_code like any ('STR1%', 'STR2%')
```